# mule : How to maintain sessions in Web Service consumer

Tags: session, mule, netsuite

I am trying to add a record in NetSuite by using the same JSESSIONID returned during login call. I fetched the JESSIONID value from cookie header and set it as outbound property for JSESSIONID. And then I am doing add operation using Web Service Consumer. But I am getting the error as Invalid Session ID.
Any ideas on how to use the same session id in subsequent calls to NetSuite.

```
<set-property propertyName="JSESSIONID" value="#[flowVars.sessionID]" doc:name="Property"/>
        <set-payload value=" &lt;urn:add xmlns:urn=&quot;urn:messages_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com&quot; xmlns:urn1=&quot;urn:core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com&quot; xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xmlns:list=&quot;urn:relationships_2017_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com&quot;&gt;
         &lt;urn:record xsi:type=&quot;list:Customer&quot;&gt;
                &lt;list:companyName&gt;ABC&lt;/list:companyName&gt;
                &lt;list:subsidiary internalId=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;
         &lt;/urn:record&gt;
 &lt;/urn:add&gt;" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="add" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To persist or maintain application state/session ,you can leverage Object store in Mule.
You can store the JSESSIONID/map of JSESSIONID for particular user in object store and use it in subsequent requests.
Remove them once session is lost/timeout.
Try to explore below links

[Managing Application Data Storage with Object Stores](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/managing-application-data-with-object-stores)

[Object Store Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/object-store-connector)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a message enricher or have your session id in some header because it may be lost after a subsequent HTTP or webservice call.